# how to let my search function allow lowercase, or ignore case sensitivity in android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i created a search functionality and everything works perfectly except that when the letter is lower case it doesn't retrieve any values but when it is uppercase it does.

how do i make it case insensitive?

My search text change listener:

```
searchShops.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
            searchInDB(s.toString());
        } else {
            searchInDB("");
        }
    }
});
```

and my searchInDB function:

```
private void searchInDB(final String s) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Shops").orderBy("name").startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                arrayList.clear();
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot DocumentSnapshot : querySnapshot) {
                    final Shop shop = DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Shop.class);
                    arrayList.add(shop);
                }
                SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Log.d("", "Error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not have case-insensitive searches.  It will only match exact strings, or in your specific case, exact string prefixes for values of the "name" field.

Usually what people do to work around this is add another field just for querying.  You could add a new field called "nameSearch" and make sure that:

- nameSearch is always a lowercase version of name.
- nameSearch is only queried by the client with fully lowercase string values.

Comment: but then wouldn't i have the same problem if a user starts his search with an uppercase letter? i want it to work both ways, either small or capital letter

Comment: You would covert what they type into lowercase to use for searching.  That's my second bullet point.